# How to establish *theoretically* which Bravais lattice an atom element (or composite of atoms) of periodic Mendeleiev Table corresponds to?

Tags: solid-state-physics, crystals

How to establish *theoretically* which Bravais lattice an atom element (or composite of atoms) of periodic Mendeleiev Table corresponds to ?

Comment: The same atomic species can form different lattices, cf. diamond vs graphite.

Comment: @Ruslan : thank you, but so, is there a *theoretical* way to know the lattice, or set of lattice, for a given element ? Or could only experiment give the answer ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to predict, without recourse to experiment, the crystalline structure of every one component system made by the periodic table elements.

Of course, one has to provide information about the thermodynamic state (say at least temperature and pressure) of interest.

Due to the need of a proper treatment of quantum electrons, the prediction would imply numerical solution of the electronic problem. However, nowadays computational packages  for electronic structure calculations (many of them based on Density Functional Theory) provide accurate and reliable data. Then, always using numerical methods, one has to find which is the favorite atomic structure from the thermodynamic point of view.

This last step can be done by *brute force*, by evaluating the relevant free energy for a list of candidate structures, or can be efficiently performed with *ad hoc* molecular dynamics algorithms like the cell variable simulation method introduced by [Parrinello and Rahman](https://cms.mpi.univie.ac.at/vasp/vasp/Parrinello_Rahman_dynamics.html).

Comment: thank you very much for the explanations

Comment: The trick is, of course, having a _complete_ list of candidate structures. This problem starts with Mn and gets worse in the actinides and beyond as new crystal structures appear on your list.

Comment: @JonCuster It is necessary for a brute force approach. Not necessary with Parrinello-Rahman method in connection with ab-initio MD (but in that case one needs longer calculation times).

Comment: Ah, but then you need a validated MD potential, and one of the prime ways to validate it is to show that the appropriate crystal phase is the stable phase at STP. And then you have things like Fe where magnetic effects are very important in making the bcc phase rather than hcp stable at STP.

Comment: @JonCuster I was speaking of *ab-initio* MD. A part technicalities, the only input is the atomic number of the element. No classical (effective potential) at all.

Comment: You have far more faith in those techniques than I do. In my experience there is significant tweaking of any computation method to get reasonable answers. This includes DFT, often used in ab-initio MD. There is no magic bullet.

Comment: @JonCuster it is not faith. I have some direct and indirect experience. Certainly it is not an easy walk. But it is feasible.

Comment: As @JonCuster says, manganese is difficult. I doubt that it is even possible when one includes the known structure.

Comment: @Pieter like this? https://journals.aps.org/prb/pdf/10.1103/PhysRevB.68.014407?casa_token=65F2f5nAYL0AAAAA%3AVehDgZhiWH6ZHAHGYrI4RRs1J042pDcF_y8XumjOW6pvRBEN8VYuAoSBI_aupAfXJ_NNiWFVgas

Comment: Heroic work but they emphasize what they got right. This paper says that Hobbs et al does not really agree with experiment: https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.101.075115